# How can I re-install the stock Android 2.2 calendar?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, installation, stock-android, google-calendar

I mistakenly deleted the stock Google Calendar application from my Android 2.2 phone (Samsung Europa GT-i5500). My phone is rooted. I can't recall what program I used for the deletion, but I have backups of 4 files saved on my desktop PC:

1. com.android.calendar-[big number].apk
2. com.android.providers.calendar-[big number].apk
3. com.android.providers.calendar-[big number].properties
4. com.android.providers.calendar-[big number].tar

How can I reinstall this application using these backups?

Comment: Looks like the files you have were created by [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup&hl=en), so I'd start there.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that. I did try but I couldn't get it to work. Is there another way please?

Answer (score 1):

You can restore the calendar from your backup files. Two of them should be of interest to you.

```
com.android.calendar-[big number].apk
com.android.providers.calendar-[big number].apk
```

The first one is the actual calendar, while the second is a helper app for it that stores it's data.   To reinstall either use Titanium Backup, a file manager (there're plenty in the play store) or adb. With the latter type:

```
adb remount
adb push /path/on/pc /system/app/Calendar.apk
adb push /path/on/pc /system/app/CalendarProvider.apk
```

into the terminal. Now reboot.